# ATP and AJD stores JSON incorrectly

Tags: json, oracle, nosql, oracle-soda

I am inserting data into the collections as a JSON in the following format

```
soda insert emp {"name" : "Miller", "job" : "Programmer", "salary" : 90000}
```

When I try to retrieve it using the

```
soda get emp -f {"name":"Miller"} command
```

The returned data is in the form where the characters in upper case is converted to lower case

```
Key: A524450AC45C4B8C81D968A5E5C80B11

Content: {"name":"miller","job":"programmer","salary":90000}

----------------------------------------- 1 row selected.
```

Please can anyone help me with this issue by guiding me to what might be causing this

Comment: Not sure if thats a bug or by intent, but a workaround is to put the JSON in a file and so "soda insert emp myfile.json".  That preserves the case.  I'm asking the sqlcl team internally to clarify.

Comment: Its not an ATP thing either - can be reproduced on local databases.

Answer (score 0):

Known bug. Fixed in SQLcl 20.4.  Workaround is to use a file as input or via PL/SQL.